# Discriminant Solutions Calculation Batch File (Square Root) (Follow up)

Tags: batch-file, calculator, equation, square-root

I am trying to create a program that has the user input 3 values which the program then proceeds and uses as the A, B and C respectively in the `ax^2+bx+c` (discriminant = D) and gives you the "solutions" it has (if `D>0` then 2 solutions, if `D = 0` one "double" solution and if `D < 0` it will display that there are no real solutions).

```
@echo off

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

:arxh
cls
echo *****************************************
echo *Theleis na trekseis to programma (Y/N)?*
echo *****************************************
set /p V=
if /I %V%==Y goto start 
if /I %V%==N goto end
echo ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
echo ~Kane thn swsth epilogh!~ 
echo ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
pause
goto arxh

:start
echo --------------------
echo Dwse mou thn timh A:
echo --------------------
set /p A=
echo --------------------
echo Dwse mou thn timh B:
echo --------------------
set /p B=
echo --------------------
echo Dwse mou thn timh C:
echo --------------------
set /p C=
goto calculation 

:calculation
set /a D=%B%*%B%-4*%A%*%C% 
echo **************************************************************************
echo ----------------------
echo Timh diakrinousas: %D%
echo ----------------------
if %D% LSS 0 goto error
if %D% GTR 0 goto positive
if %D%==0 goto zero

:error
echo ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
echo ~Arnhtikh timh diakrinousas! Den uparxoun pragmatikes luseis!~
echo ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
pause
goto arxh


:positive

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set count=0
set /p dend=Vale edw thn timh ths diakrinousas: 
set num=%dend%
for /l %%i in (%dend%, -1, 1) do (
   set /a sqr=%%i*%%i
   if !sqr! leq %dend% (
      set digit=%%i.
     set root=%%i
      goto out
   )
)

:out
   call set /a count+=1
   if %count% GTR 5 goto next
   set /a dend=(%dend%-%sqr%)*100
   set /a div=%root%*2
   for /l %%i in (9,-1,0) do (
      set /a sqr=%div%%%i*%%i
      if !sqr! leq %dend% (
         set root=%root%%%i
         goto out
      )
   )

:next   
   set root=%root:~-5%
   if %dend% neq 0 set digit=%digit%%root%
goto results

:results
set /p S=%digit%
set /a Q=(-%B%+%S%)/2*%A%
set /a R=(-%B%-%S%)/2*%A%
echo ----------------------------------------------------
echo H prwth riza einai ~%Q%~ kai h deuterh einai ~%R%~ !
echo ----------------------------------------------------
echo *****************Approximate Value*******************
pause
goto arxh


:zero
set /a Z=-b/2*A
echo -------------------------
echo H diplh riza einai: %Z% !
echo -------------------------
pause
goto arxh

:end
end
```

I found a program that the user inputs a number and it finds the square root of said number! I converted the code, so that the user would not input that number, but instead the number would be the discriminant (the number A,B and C would make in the equation).

No matter how hard i try, I get `missing operants` errors or `unbalanced parenthesis` or it displays to me the root of the discriminant but doesn't proceed to use it correctly in the equations below. Seriously I am stuck.

Some help would be appreciated!

P.S. don't run the code snippet, I am new here, so I used that tool to display the code.

Thank you in any case

Comment: You are trying to break out of a `FOR /L` command.  That is not possible. All iterations will process regardless of your `GOTO OUT`  command. If you need it to break out then use a regular FOR command. `for %%i in (9  8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0) do (`  You sure you didn't want that `GOTO OUT` to be `GOTO NEXT`?

Comment: the part between :positive and :results is the part that i found online (the part that can calculate the square root of a number). To be absolutely honest, i am STILL trying to figure out step by step what exactly it does. I am new in programming (i am in a school for that) and i am trying to figure out the code i use before i use it.
The way i understand it is that the program repeats the contents of :out until %count% becomes greater than 5. Why it does that? I do not understand. But if that part of the code (:positive to :results) runs alone, it calculates the square root of a number.

Comment: Any `SET /A` operands (numbers) must all be within the range of 32 bit signed integer. **Dot is not allowed** (see calculations under `:results` label.) A fractional result will be rounded down to the nearest whole integer.

Comment: i made it so that it would always pick %D% as a number, whatever that becomes, and then runs it through until %D%'s square root is found. Then, supposedly, it takes that value and runs it through 

set /a Q=(-%B%+%S%)/2*%A%
set /a R=(-%B%-%S%)/2*%A%

and i get 2 results Q and R which then i display to the user.

(note: " set /p dend=Vale edw thn timh ths diakrinousas: " is asking the user to put the value of D manually, dont mind that, i was just experimenting, treat it as " set /p dend=%D% " )

Comment: @JosefZ i am with you, but if you take the part under :positive and above :results it calculates square roots with decimals!

Comment: Treat it as `set dend=%D%`.  Note that `set /p S=%digit%` seems to be wrong as well (requires user's response). On `Enter`, then in `set /a Q=(-%B%+%S%)/2*%A%` is missing operand `%S%`.  Unfortunately, this command leads to `Unbalanced parenthesis` if used `set S=%digit%` as `%digit%` contains a dot.

Comment: currently i managed to make it work changing it with " set /a S=%digit% "
(which while returning "missing operator" if you see it without @echo off, it takes the value WITH decimals, but the two solutions Q,R return as integers. (i.e insted of -0.08 you get 0) the part that calculates the square root of a number, can actually return a decimal at the end (echo etc) how would someone be able to do that?? i am reading up on the subject and everyone says you need outside supplements, yet i have none enabled.)

Comment: Plain and Simple, the `SET /A` command does not do floating point math and never will.  You can simulate it with some complex functions but it can't do it out of the box. There was a guy who went by the name of Judago that wrote some floating point math batch files many years ago but his website is no longer available. If you want to do floating point math then call out to powershell and capture the output with a `FOR /F` command.